# Proving Two Homotopic Maps Produce the Same Homomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Here's the problem as stated in John Lee's book:

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are connected spaces, and the fundamental group of $Y$ is abelian.  Show that if $F, G: X \to Y$ are homotopic maps such that $F(x) = G(x)$ for some $x \in X$ then $F_*= G_*: \pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_1(Y, F(x))$.  Give a counterexample to show that this might not be true if $\pi_1(Y)$ is not abelian.

I feel like I can only put together the basic ideas in this problem but I can't piece them together.  Since $F$ and $G$ are homotopic there is a continuous map $H:X\times I \to Y$ such that $H(s,0) = F$ and $H(s,1) = G$.  Unfortunately this doesn't guarantee that $H(x,t) = F(x) = G(x)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.  Is there a way to guarantee such a homotopy exists?  Does it not matter?  If this were possible then we could argue that if $[f] \in \pi_1(X,x)$ then $[H(f(s),t)]$ guarantees that $[F\circ f] = [G\circ f]$ thus $F_*[f] = G_*[f]$.  Aside from the problem that $H$ may not fix the point $F(x)$, this potential proof would not explain why $\pi_1(Y)$ being abelian or having $X$ and $Y$ connected are necessary presumptions.

Additionally, if someone can point me in the direction of some non-commutative counterexamples I would appreciate it.  When I think about spaces I know fairly well they seem to have abelian fundamental groups: $S^n, \; S^1\times S^1, \; \mathbb{RP}^2$, etc.

Please provide suggestions and hints only.

Comment: You should expand your repertoire of simple examples to include some simple non-manifold cell complexes, such as bouquets of circles.

Comment: @Neal That's a fair suggestion, but I'm fairly new to this material and am not sure of techniques on how to actually find the fundamental groups of different spaces.  Is there a concise way I can compute the fundamental group of the figure-8 space, say?  Or am I better off looking up its fundamental group and learning the techniques later on?

Comment: There are theorems for computing the fundamental group, like Seifert-van Kampen. There are also "common-sense" methods, where you draw a picture, write down generators, and then derive relations. (This is how you'd find $\pi_1$ of the figure-8 knot complement -- look up "Wirtinger presentation.") Of course these require proof underpinning them. There is also a general correspondence between constructions and relationships in group theory and geometry -- subgroups $\leftrightarrow$ covering spaces, relations $\leftrightarrow$ gluing disks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

HINTS: try to observe that given any loop $\gamma(t)$ starting at $x_0$ $F\circ \gamma(t)$ and $G\circ \gamma(t)$ are loops in $Y$ starting at $F(x_0)=G(x_0)$  .Now claim is that there is some $[g] \in \pi_1(Y,F(x_0))$ s.t $[F\circ \gamma]$ =$[g]*[G\circ\gamma]*[g]^{-1}$...try to find this $[g]$??

For a counter example cosider $F: S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ s.t upper half of the circle winding once(anticlock wise direction) around the circle generated by loop $a$ and lower half of the circle winding around(anti-clockwise direction) once to the other circle generated by loop $b$ s.t $F(1)=F(-1)= $ common intersecting point of two circles...and $G: S^1\to S^1\vee S^1$ s.t upper half of the circle winding around (anticlockwise) once to the circle $b$ and then the circle $a$... then $F_* \pi_1(S^1,1) =\langle ab\rangle$ and $G_* \pi_1(S^1,1)=\langle ba\rangle$. I think this much hint is enough for you to figure out the rest

Comment: I've been thinking for a while about how to construct such a loop $[g] \in \pi_1(Y, F(x_0))$ but I'm really not sure how to approach this.  What should I consider in doing so?  Does the connectedness of $X$ and/or $Y$ play a role?

Comment: HINTS: try to see the behavior of the loop $H(x_0,t)$